# why does the browser freeze when executing many ajax requests?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a page that is executing around 200 ajax requests using jquery.load but it is behaving in a very un-ajax way because the browser is frozen while the results are fetched.

By freezing I mean losing control of the browser, not able to scroll it up and down even. Then the results all display at once when it has finished all requests, but I know it is actually fetching the results 6 at a time (browser controlled "same host" policy) from watching the access log of the target server.

Though the jquery.load commands are built using a "foreach" loop they are already written to the source of the page when the user loads it (so for all intents and purposes they could all be hand written individually), so its not like the page is waiting for the loop to finish. The last "symptom" is that even if it is only 30 requests instead, the issue is just the same.

So it's odd to me and I am looking for ideas of what could cause this and how it could be worked around. It's definitely confusing to the end user especially as it could take 90-100 seconds until all the responses are back and the user regains control of the browser.

**One small update:**

I have very similar code running in another webapp that does around 20 requests simultaneously without issue. The difference is that instead of fetching a page, it is ssh'ing to the server and reading/updating a file on the file system via a script. I would have thought that would actually have a little more overhead but it has none of these issues.

And as I have said - even 20 requests causes the same issue with the code in question... so I am tempted to think its perhaps curl related... though its pure speculation.

**The Bigger update Now with infinitely more Code!!!**

The fuller background to app is this. We run a cluster of some of the highest trafficked WebSphere AppServers in the world, which are running our Commerce applications. The intensity of the traffic means that if we simply let traffic on to an appserver before the JVM is warmed up, they crash! So we hit a few key pages before allowing traffic on, as this precompiles all the major servlets, proportions the JVM, and populates some of the servlet caches. Then the traffic can come onto the server with no issues and they run great.

We had a version of the app written in CGI which worked but was so slow due to being synchronous. We are talking about 10 minutes on some clusters to run.  Due to being synchronous requests, only one thread on the appserver and one jdbc connection was being used.

So what the new webapp does is use a template of these key pages, to combine with a bunch of market definitions (country code, language code, catalog id's etc) to produce a list of all those URL's that need to be hit. By hitting them all in an asynchronous way it not only runs faster (now taking only 90 seconds), it also does a better job of proportioning the JVM, uses up to 30 threads and opens the JDBC pool to its full number of connections. Thus it's REALLY in a production-like state by the time we let traffic on. So I am very pleased with results, but this browser freeze is annoying me from a purely cosmetic and puzzle-solving point of view.

So now some code, the user simply selects an appserver, the app decides which cluster it is from, and displays the list of computed URL's it will hit. At this point the page is a table of 'Markets x Urls' with each cell having a unique id that the jquery uses to put the right result in the right cell (as we can't guarantee the order in which the results come back - nor do we want to as that takes us back into synchronous territory again.

So at the point at which the user is ready to click Go, the table is written and the jQuery commands prepared. On clicking go the jquery script is executed and URL's are hit and return a HTTP status code for each so we know they were successful.

The JQ part generated looks like (shortened to just a few markets)

```
$("a#submit").click(function(event) {
    alert(" booya ");
    $("#sesv-1").load("psurl.php?server=servera.domain.com&url=/se/sv");
    $("#sesv-2").load("psurl.php?server=servera.domain.com&url=/se/sv/catalog/productsaz/");
    $("#sesv-3").load("psurl.php?server=servera.domain.com&url=/se/sv/catalog/products/12345678");
    $("#sesv-4").load("psurl.php?server=servera.domain.com&url=/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/StockSearch?storeId=14&productId=103406&StoreNumber=099&langId=-13&ddkey=http:StockSearch");
    $("#sesv-5").load("psurl.php?server=servera.domain.com&url=/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/StockSearch?query=testProd&storeId=14&langId=-11&StoreNumber=011");
    $("#atde-1").load("psurl.php?server=servera.domain.com&url=/at/de");
    $("#atde-2").load("psurl.php?server=servera.domain.com&url=/at/de/catalog/productsaz/");
    $("#atde-3").load("psurl.php?server=servera.domain.com&url=/at/de/catalog/products/12345678");
    $("#atde-4").load("psurl.php?server=servera.domain.com&url=/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/StockSearch?storeId=1&productId=103406&StoreNumber=114&langId=-99&ddkey=http:StockSearch");
    $("#atde-5").load("psurl.php?server=servera.domain.com&url=/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/StockSearch?query=testProd&storeId=1&langId=-21&StoreNumber=273");
    $("#benl-1").load("psurl.php?server=servera.domain.com&url=/be/nl");
    $("#benl-2").load("psurl.php?server=servera.domain.com&url=/be/nl/catalog/productsaz/");
    $("#benl-3").load("psurl.php?server=servera.domain.com&url=/be/nl/catalog/products/12345678");
    $("#benl-4").load("psurl.php?server=servera.domain.com&url=/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/StockSearch?storeId=18&productId=103406&StoreNumber=412&langId=-44&ddkey=http:StockSearch");
    $("#benl-5").load("psurl.php?server=servera.domain.com&url=/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/StockSearch?query=testProd&storeId=18&langId=-23&StoreNumber=482");
    $("#befr-1").load("psurl.php?server=servera.domain.com&url=/be/fr");
    $("#befr-2").load("psurl.php?server=servera.domain.com&url=/be/fr/catalog/productsaz/");
    $("#befr-3").load("psurl.php?server=servera.domain.com&url=/be/fr/catalog/products/12345678");
    $("#befr-4").load("psurl.php?server=servera.domain.com&url=/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/StockSearch?storeId=130&productId=103406&StoreNumber=048&langId=-73&ddkey=http:StockSearch");
    $("#befr-5").load("psurl.php?server=servera.domain.com&url=/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/StockSearch?query=testProd&storeId=130&langId=-24&StoreNumber=482");
    $("#caen-1").load("psurl.php?server=servera.domain.com&url=/ca/en");
    $("#caen-2").load("psurl.php?server=servera.domain.com&url=/ca/en/catalog/productsaz/");
    $("#caen-3").load("psurl.php?server=servera.domain.com&url=/ca/en/catalog/products/12345678");
    $("#caen-4").load("psurl.php?server=servera.domain.com&url=/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/StockSearch?storeId=30&productId=103406&StoreNumber=006&langId=-11&ddkey=http:StockSearch");
    $("#caen-5").load("psurl.php?server=servera.domain.com&url=/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/StockSearch?query=testProd&storeId=30&langId=-15&StoreNumber=216");
    $("#cafr-1").load("psurl.php?server=servera.domain.com&url=/ca/fr");
    $("#cafr-2").load("psurl.php?server=servera.domain.com&url=/ca/fr/catalog/productsaz/");
    $("#cafr-3").load("psurl.php?server=servera.domain.com&url=/ca/fr/catalog/products/12345678");
    $("#cafr-4").load("psurl.php?server=servera.domain.com&url=/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/StockSearch?storeId=33&productId=103406&StoreNumber=124&langId=-09&ddkey=http:StockSearch");
    $("#cafr-5").load("psurl.php?server=servera.domain.com&url=/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/StockSearch?query=testProd&storeId=33&langId=-16&StoreNumber=216")
    });
});
```

The PS URL is simply a curl request function that responds with 404, 200, 500 etc which is then used to populate the relevant cell.

```
function getPage( $url ) {
$options = array(
    CURLOPT_URL             => $url,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,                 // return web page
    CURLOPT_HEADER         => true,                 // return headers
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,                 // follow redirects
    CURLOPT_ENCODING       => "",                   // handle all encodings
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => "pre-surf",           // who am i
    CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER    => true,                 // set referer on redirect
    CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 120,                  // timeout on connect
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 120,                  // timeout on response
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS      => 10,                   // stop after 10 redirects
    CURLOPT_POST            => 0,                   // i am not sending post data
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 0,                    // don't verify ssl
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => FALSE,                //
);

$ch      = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
$content = curl_exec($ch);
$err     = curl_errno($ch);
$errmsg  = curl_error($ch) ;
$header  = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close($ch);

//  $header['errno']   = $err;
//  $header['errmsg']  = $errmsg;
//  $header['content'] = $content;
return $header['http_status_code'];
}
```

Comment: "200 ajax requests" That's why.

Comment: 200 ajax requests is 200 http requests...like opening 200 tabs simultaneously in your browser...no wonder it gets slow

Comment: Are any of those requests synchronous on top of just being numerous?

Comment: Without code - can't really help. Are these 200 requests simultaneous? Even if they aren't it sounds like a heck of a lot. For starters - enable Firebug / Developer console to view the network activity

Comment: Why do you need such a large number of requests? It would be far more efficient to consolidate them into 1 due to the 'browser controlled "same host" policy'. However, I'm not sure why it is actually causing the browser to lock up; does it lock up all browsers? or are you only testing in IE.

Comment: There's something wrong with the core design of the page that fires 200 ajax requests for single page access. Also, are you using synchronous or asynchronous transfer? You could provide some code before further advices are given.

Comment: 200 ajax requests... that is horrible like a tumblr with 200 gifs! ajax does not mean magic, those are 200 HTTP requests, e.g. 200 tabs in a browser.

Comment: The browser tab analogy isn't really applicable. There's a lot of overhead that goes with a tab (memory allocation, potentially a new process/thread). There's also a lot of difference between pulling down a piece of JSON from the interwebs and loading, deciphering and rendering a complete web page. However, 200 AJAX requests is still a lot for one page (not arguing that) -- it's just not really even close to 200 tabs.

Comment: You might benefit strongly from some better database management. It seems like you are using an ajax call for each record, rather than pulling the entire view/table in one request. By changing how you access the data, you should be able to stop this 200 calls nonsense.

Comment: don't kill your browser not your server... 200 request are way than a page requires... try to build up more tasks on one ajax request instead of doing seperate request for every single tasks

Comment: Can you even perform 200 requests at once? I thought you were limited at most depending on the browser used to about 8 without tweaking it and it'd just queue them? Still a crazy amount :/

Comment: @lloyd yes exactly right. According to browserscope, FF, IE and Chrome all limit it to 6 at a time to the same host (which it is in this case). So even though there are 200 ajax requests fired ... there is a built in browser 'queue' of 6

Comment: @KevinB - on further testing its actually better in firefox. It freezes a little at the start and then it actually updates quite nicely. IE and Chrome updates for after the first 6 then freezes until complete

Comment: @Jlange there is no database involved - they are simple curl requests that respond with an HTTP Status code

Comment: @DanJ .load is asynchronous by default

Comment: @N.B. and all the rest of you kind responders, I will post some specific code in the morning when I am back at my work machine. But each request is a simple .load of a tiny php page which performs a curl request to the production web server. Its a 3 byte response (i.e. the 3 characters of an http status code).

Comment: Why don't you just do 1 jQuery.load with an array of URLs you want to inspect and have the php script query all of them and return an array of results? That way you won't spawn unnecessary threads by issuing more than 1 http request and browser will have to take care of only 1 outgoing connection instead of 200. There probably will be a "hang" until the request completes, but you can remedy that by displaying a loading icon or something until cURL completes all requests.

Comment: @N.B. yeah, its an approach I thought about, and when it boils down to it I think if it was the highest priority to provide a 'nice' browser session it would be a method I would settle for. But it is also 'nice' for a technician to know "great, now the french market is finished I can let france in" before all the results are back. Having said that, now that the whole process is taking only 90 seconds its perhaps an unlikely scenario compared to the old 10 minute script. Its a question of function versus form right now I guess.

Comment: The mystery to me though is still why with only 6 requests at a time allowed by the browser, it is enough to hang the browser... surely queued requests are not the issue as they are not exactly heavy chunks of code. I think epascarello answer below is a likely source of testing for me and I will start to do some testing based on DOM updates and batching I think.

Answer (score 4):

The problem here is not the Ajax requests, the problem is each one of those requests is updating the DOM. The browser redraw is what is causing the browser to lock up.

You need to find a better solution that does not write to the DOM so often.

Comment: You think its frequency of the dom updates? i.e. how close to each other they are? I did try to look into some queuing / batch methods but couldn't really find anything useful. Overall 200 requests over 90 seconds is like 2 updates per second. But in the cases where its around 20-30 updates over 90 seconds, its one 3 byte update of the dom every 3 seconds on average ... and still the problem exists.

Comment: @Seer here's some info that might be useful: http://wilsonpage.co.uk/preventing-layout-thrashing/  though I've never used the 'fastdom' library he went on to write, the technique it's using to update the DOM is gaining popularity.